# how to check if a string matches a pattern with asterisk

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list of files:

```
var files = [
    "user_parse_info",
    "user_parse_age",
    "site_render_info",
    "site_parse_name"
]
```

Now I have string a pattern:

```
var pattern = "site_*_name";
```

This should match only the last file.
How can I check this? Maybe an RegExp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, regular expression would be a better choice for this.

```
var _ = require('nimble');

var files = [
    "user_parse_info",
    "user_parse_age",
    "site_render_info",
    "site_parse_name"
];

var re = /^site_.*_name$/;

var result = _.filter(files, function (val) {
     return re.test(val);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess is something wrong. take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/4C5z9/1/

Comment: great :) you can use nimble to iterate throw array

Comment: great job! If we put braces it works also... (site_)*(_name) http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/jDA2B/

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression means that you would need to escape some characters like `.` and `$`, otherwise they can give false positives or keep the pattern from matching anything.

You can just split the string on the asterisk and check the parts against the string:

```
var parts = pattern.split('*');

if (
  str.length >= parts[0].length + parts[1].length &&
  str.substr(0, parts[0].length) == parts[0] &&
  str.substr(str.length - parts[1].length) == parts[1])
{
  // matches
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/u8XEE/

Comment: This is the best solution as it is pure JS. No server side JS or require() needed.